# Find all entire functions having a root

Tags: complex-analysis

**EDIT:** I am asking just by curiosity, this is not an assignment. Usually I think hard about my mathematical doubts, but this time I am (both) curious and lazy.

> Determine all the sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ in $\mathbb C$ such that the function $f$ given by $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is entire and takes the value $0$.

The fundamental theorem of algebra guarantees that sequences $(a_n)$ with $a_n=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large satisfy the required conditions. I would like to know if all the other sequences have already determined elsewhere.

Comment: Is this an assignment or have you thought this question out? (this is useful to know because if it is not an assignment, it could be tremendously difficult to answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic facts about entire functions:

1. [Picards theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) says that any non-constant entire function takes all values in $\mathbb{C}$ except possibly a single value. This already tell us than *almost all* entire functions have a zero.
2. The entire functions that do not have a zero [can be written](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267805/f-is-entire-without-any-zeros-then-there-is-an-entire-function-g-such-that) (see also [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem)) on the form $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ for some entire function $g$.
3. $f$ is entire if and only if the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ [satisfy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n} = 0$.

Based on these facts we have that *almost all* sequences that satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n} = 0$ will produce an entire function that has a zero. Those that do not are most easily described by their functional form rather than by the sequence $a_n$.